# Python define a multilevel print function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a python script to test an embedded device.

My python script contains several simple tests that are repeated.
Each simple test has some print in order to show the test output.

Since, if I run simple test for several times, there will be a lot of print output, my idea is to define a function that wraps the print but inside this function I can check the debug level.

Let me explain:

1. I define a global variable DEBUG_LEVEL = true
2. If I invoke NewPrint(messageToPrint, DEBUG_LEVEL). 
   The messageToPrint is printed
3. I define a global variable DEBUG_LEVEL = false
4. If I invoke NewPrint(messageToPrint, DEBUG_LEVEL). 
   The messageToPrint is not printed

What I don't how to do is to define a new function that can get additiona argument like the standard print:

> print("Error creating socket: %s" % e)

I did a similar thing in C using argv...but I had less skill in python programming.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Best regards,
Federico

Comment: Why not use the built-in logging library? Which has all the levels you need.

Comment: @JasonChia Thank you. This is a good starting point!